# How to reduce usage of geometry reader in a LazyVgrid?

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader, lazyvgrid

In this code, is it a problem usage of geometryReader both in view and in cells? is there a different way to achieve same result?).
to be clear if I have 5 cells, I had hard time keeping the image in the same position even if text is on single line. I need to avoid getting some cell with image close to top and other at a lower position

I'd like to keep these requirements:

- the images should be at the same level in each cells, if the text is on a single line, I need the image is same "level" of cells where text is on two lines.
- I'd like to avoid hard coded sizes, this way hopefully the views are more flexible

  ```
   import SwiftUI

   struct TestForBackgroundImage: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    private static let minCommonWidth: CGFloat = 100
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: minCommonWidth))]

    var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { item in
                        ItemView(item: item)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print(item)
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
        }
            .backgroundImage2()

    }

    private struct ItemView: View {
        let item: Int

        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                    //                        Image(AppConstants.FixedImages.backgroundImage.rawValue)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.4, height: geometry.size.width * 0.4)
                    //this one is here for testing multiple text lenghts to be certain the image is always at the same level in each cell
                    if item % 2 == 0 {
                        Text("short: \(item)")
                            .frame(height: geometry.size.width * 0.25)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                    } else {
                        Text("middle lenght text: \(item)")
                            .frame(height: geometry.size.width * 0.25)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width)
                .background(.teal)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
            }
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        }
    } 
   }







    struct BackgroundImage2: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .background(
                    Image(AppConstants.FixedImages.backgroundImage.rawValue)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .opacity(0.4)
                        .offset(x: -geometry.size.width / 2, y:      geometry.size.height / 2)
                )
        }
    }
   }

  extension View {
    func backgroundImage2() -> some View {
        modifier(BackgroundImage2())
    }
    }
  ```

Comment: What do you mean "the images should be at the same level"? What is a "level"? Do you mean the y position?

Comment: yes, If I have 5 cells, I had hard time keeping the image in the same position even if text is on single line. I need to avoid getting some cell with image close to top and other at a lower position

Comment: Does each `ItemView` have to have 1:1 aspect ratio?

Comment: in this specific case, yes. But I'd like to understand which is, if there is one, the best practice for maintaining a layout in a cell where images are not "jumping" up and down depending how many lines the text is requiring.

Comment: If you want 1:1 aspect ratio then using a `GeometryReader` to do `.frame(height: geometry.size.width * 0.25)` is totally fine. If you don't care about aspect ratio, then you can just add a `Spacer()` in the stack and `scaleToFit` the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the 1:1 aspect ratio, you can just `scaleToFit` the image, and add a `Spacer` between the text and the image (or after the text, depending on what alignment you want):

```
// ItemView's body:
VStack {
    Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
    Spacer()
    if item % 2 == 0 {
        Text("short: \(item)")
            .lineLimit(2)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
    } else {
        Text("middle lenght text: \(item)")
            .lineLimit(2)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
    }
}
.background(.teal)
.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
```

The spacer pushes the image and text apart from each other, making sure that the images always align at the top.

[image]

If you are not satisfied with this, then I suggest keeping the `GeometryReader`. Making the `Text` 1/4 of the height of the `VStack` is very reasonable.

Otherwise, you can put an invisible 2-line text, and overlay the actual text on top of it. IMO, this is more of a hack when compared to `GeometryReader`.

```
VStack{
    Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
    // this takes up 2 lines
    Text("\n")
        .lineLimit(2)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
        .padding(.top, 5)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay { // specify the alignment here, if needed
            Group {
                if item % 2 == 0 {
                    Text("short: \(item)")
                } else {
                    Text("middle lenght text: \(item)")
                }
            }
            .lineLimit(2)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
        }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
.background(.teal)
.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
```

[image]

Comment: My concerns are about performance geometry reader, I'm not sure if it is that heavy as someone told me. After that, your first solution could be good, but putting the Spacer after the text. But, in that case I still cannot manage the size of images, my final result should be something close to apple size in your second picture.

Comment: @biggreentree What do you mean by "manage the size of images"? That is not in your list of requirements. You can make the images smaller by adding `padding`. And anyway, isn't it one of your goals to *not* hardcode anything about size? And, are you *sure* the performance of `GeometryReader` is affecting your app? Have you done profiling? What about the second solution with overlays? Is there anything wrong you don't like about that?